# Can singleton be an open set?

Tags: general-topology

All singletons are closed sets, but can they be open sets?

By the definition of an isolated point, x in set X is an isolated point of X if {x} is open in X.
I just can't understand how singleton could be open:

$$ \left\{x \right\} \ \mathrm{is \ open \ in} \ X. \ \Leftrightarrow \ \exists r>0: \ \mathcal{B}_r \left(x \right)  \subset \left\{x \right\} $$

Is it possible to have an open ball with radius r in a singleton?

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual metric. (And in general topological spaces as opposed to metric spaces, singletons don't always need to be closed - consider e.g. the indiscrete topology on a set with more than one element.)

Comment: @Noah Schweber: In case you're interested, [singletons don't even have to be Borel](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-80/issue-1/When-is-a-point-Borel/pjm/1102785960.full).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Consider the metric $d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0,&x=y\\1,&x\ne y\end{cases}$. Then $B_r(x)=\{x\}$ for any $r\le1$.

Moreover, consider any finite set  $S=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ under any metric $\rho$. Take $d=\frac12\min_{x_i\ne x_j}\{\rho(x_i,x_j)\}>0$. Then $B_d(x_i)$ does not contain any other $x_j$ in $S$. Thus $B_d(x_i)=\{x_i\}$. That is, in a finite metric space every subset is clopen and the topology induced by the metric is the discrete topology.